# AFNetworking+UIImageView: Duplicate images after fast scroll

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, afnetworking

I have a collection view that is supposed to display a large collection of images from a server. I get all the image info from the server as one big JSON request, turn them into my own photo objects(`POPhoto`), then display them in the collection as shown below. The problem is if I scroll fast, some cell that had previously been displayed will come into view with their previous image set, then if I stop the scroll, I can watch the image suddenly change to something else.

It seems like AFNetworking is not cancelling the request when the cell moves off screen and reappears in a different position. So if I scroll to the middle of my photos, then back to the top, the cells at the top will first appear with the images they had originally, but will then switch to other photos that belong to the middle of the list.

**My PhotoCell class**:

```
-(void)setPhoto:(POPhoto *)p
{
    self->photo = p;

    p.delegate = self;
    self.progressView.hidden = YES;

    if (p.thumbnail != nil) {
        self.imageView.image = p.thumbnail;
    }
    else if (p.thumbnailURLPath != nil)
    {
        NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:p.thumbnailURLPath]];

        UIImage* placeholder = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"placeholder.png"];
        __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
        [self.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request
                              placeholderImage:placeholder
                                       success:^(NSURLRequest* request, NSHTTPURLResponse* response, UIImage* image) {
                                           weakSelf.imageView.image = image;
                                           weakSelf.photo.thumbnail = image;
                                       }
                                       failure:nil];
    }
}
```

**My collection view:**

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    POPhotoCell* photoCell = (POPhotoCell*)[self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kPhotoCellReuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (photoCell == nil) {
        NSArray* topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"POPhotoCell" owner:self options:nil];
        photoCell = (POPhotoCell*)[topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    photoCell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"polaroid1"]];
    [photoCell setPhoto:self.photos[indexPath.row]];
    return photoCell;
}
```

Comment: My intuition would say that because those cells are being recycled, the success block from every previous reuse will still be executed regardless of the cell state, causing each previously downloaded image to be the placeholder for the next.

Comment: Hmm... Ok. I guess if that's the reason, then checking the request in the success block to make sure it matches the current photo's URL should fix it.

Comment: No, you need to associate the image to your POPhoto object.That is, POPhoto should have a property `image`. However, without a cache you likely get memory issues. And, without a more "sophisticate" cache and  some "look ahead" algorithm which prepares your images *before* they shall become visible, you likely experience "stutter".

Comment: Looks like John's comment was correct. Checking the URL in the success block seems to fix it.

@CouchDeveloper: I don't understand why I'd do that, since  AFNetworking already handles caching for me.